fetch image from registry and use it in pipeline
I am trying to write a
git-ci.yml 
where I need to fetch a docker image from container registry and deploy it on remote server though
docker compose.
How can I achieve that?
I tried something like this, I know its not accurate and I dont have enough knowledge about CI/CD.
I need to pull Image01 and run docker-compose on it.
default:
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - name: docker:dind

stages:
  - deploy

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"

Deploy:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - wcs-staging-deploy
  script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker pull $Image01
    - eval `ssh-agent`
    - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_KEY")
    - DOCKER_HOST=“ssh://user@remotehost” docker-compose up -d

Currently I am having error as below,

error during connect: Post "http://docker:2375/v1.45/images/create?fromImage=registry.gitlab.com": dial tcp: lookup docker on 172.16.2.23:53: server misbehaving

